# REFPROP Library within CoolProp Python

Tags: python

Currently I'm using a toolbox which makes use of CoolProp. The REFPROP library is used in the coding, e.g: ... = CP.AbstractState('REFPROP', fluid).

When I run the script I get the following error message: "ValueError: You cannot use the REFPROPMixtureBackend". I don't understand how to acces the REFPROP library. I used pip install ctREFPROP and installed the "MINI-REFPROP" from NIST.

How do I introduce the REFPROP library within Python ? Is it something I have to pay for ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the path of `REFPROP` library like this:

```py
CoolProp.set_config_string(CoolProp.ALTERNATIVE_REFPROP_PATH, "C:\Program Files (x86)\MINI-REFPROP")
```

**NOTE:**
MINI-REFPROP contains a limited number of pure fluids (water, CO2, R134a, nitrogen, oxygen, methane, propane, helium, hydrogen, and dodecane), along with air as a pseudo-pure fluid.